# How can do offline validation of google id_token?

Tags: node.js, openid, google-signin

According to the documentation at https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth, `google-auth-library` allows us to verify the google id_token validity. However, is there a way to cache the jwks keys locally and avoid round trips to google servers? Or does the library takes care of this already?